# id and class selectors in css

Tags: html, css

For id, its said that id is unique and we cannot have more than one element having the same id, but in the code below, I am able to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
#para1
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}
#para2
{
color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3 id="para1">Hello World!</h3>
<p id="para1">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>

<p id="para1">Hello World!</p>
<p id="para1">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Despite still being able to use it, it's still invalid markup. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Browsers are very forgiving with HTML is very forgiving. Just because you can and it works, doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: The browser may not be too fussed and may even render any CSS for the ID without question. Though you will strike difficulties if you start using JavaScript to reference duplicated element IDs.

Comment: @JoshCrozier My question is that : how am I able to use id multiple times for the same element?

Answer (score 0):

You still able to use same ID  for multiple element, but it is not a good practice, instead of using `id`, why don't you change it to `class`?

```
<style>
  .para1
  {
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
  }
  .para2
  {
    color:blue;
  }
</style>

<h3 class="para1">Hello World!</h3>
<p class="para1">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>

<p class="para1">Hello World!</p>
<p class="para1">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>
```